# Web scraping daily informations from table using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I try to get daily informations about some investment funds from site https://stooq.com/ using Python web-scraping. All needed data (dates, prices, etc.) are inside table located in the centre of that page.

My code to start web-scraping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import datetime as dt

## The examples of investment funds list
number_to_symbol = {
    '1': '2711.n',
    '2': '3187.n',
    '3': '1472.n',
    '4': '4604.n',
    '5': '2735.n'
}

def url_get(num):
    ## Make URL address using investment fund symbol and dates range (01.01.2020 - today)
    symbol = number_to_symbol[str(num)]
    end_time = f"20{dt.date.today().strftime('%y%m%d')}"
    return f'https://stooq.com/q/d/?s={symbol}&c=0&d1=20200101&d2={end_time}&c=0'

url_name = url_get(4)
print(f'URL to web-scraping: {url_name}')
URL to web-scraping: https://stooq.com/q/d/?s=4604.n&c=0&d1=20200101&d2=20220507&c=0
```

and web-scraping method by parsing WWW site code:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url_name)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

This gave me only JS code from "The Closure Library", so it's useless (results is below):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   (function(){/* Copyright The Closure Library Authors. SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0*/'use strict';var g=function(a){var b=0;return function(){return b<a.length?{done:!1,value:a[b++]}:{done:!0}}},l=this||self,m=/^[\w+/_-]+[=]{0,2}$/,p=null,q=function(){},r=function(a){var b=typeof a;if("object"==b)if(a){if(a instanceof Array)return"array";if(a instanceof Object)return b;var c=Object.prototype.toString.call(a);if("[object Window]"==c)return"object";if("[object Array]"==c||"number"==typeof a.length&&"undefined"!=typeof a.splice&&"undefined"!=typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable&&!a.propertyIsEnumerable("splice"))return"array";if("[object Function]"==c||"undefined"!=typeof a.call&&"undefined"!=typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable&&!a.propertyIsEnumerable("call"))return"function"}else return"null";else if("function"==b&&"undefined"==typeof a.call)return"object";return b},u=function(a,b){function c(){}c.prototype=b.prototype;a.prototype=new c;a.prototype.constructor=a};var v=function(a,b){Object.defineProperty(l,a,{configurable:!1,get:function(){return b},set:q})};var y=function(a,b){this.b=a===w&&b||"";this.a=x},x={},w={};var aa=function(a,b){a.src=b instanceof y&&b.constructor===y&&b.a===x?b.b:"type_error:TrustedResourceUrl";if(null===p)b:{b=l.document;if((b=b.querySelector&&b.querySelector("script[nonce]"))&&(b=b.nonce||b.getAttribute("nonce"))&&m.test(b)){p=b;break b}p=""}b=p;b&&a.setAttribute("nonce",b)};var z=function(){return Math.floor(2147483648*Math.random()).toString(36)+Math.abs(Math.floor(2147483648*Math.random())^+new Date).toString(36)};var A=function(a,b){b=String(b);"application/xhtml+xml"===a.contentType&&(b=b.toLowerCase());return a.createElement(b)},B=function(a){this.a=a||l.document||document};B.prototype.appendChild=function(a,b){a.appendChild(b)};var C=function(a,b,c,d,e,f){try{var k=a.a,h=A(a.a,"SCRIPT");h.async=!0;aa(h,b);k.head.appendChild(h);h.addEventListener("load",function(){e();d&&k.head.removeChild(h)});h.addEventListener("error",function(){0<c?C(a,b,c-1,d,e,f):(d&&k.head.removeChild(h),f())})}catch(n){f()}};var ba=l.atob("aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ3N0YXRpYy5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2ljb25zL21hdGVyaWFsL3N5c3RlbS8xeC93YXJuaW5nX2FtYmVyXzI0ZHAucG5n"),ca=l.atob("WW91IGFyZSBzZWVpbmcgdGhpcyBtZXNzYWdlIGJlY2F1c2UgYWQgb3Igc2NyaXB0IGJsb2NraW5nIHNvZnR3YXJlIGlzIGludGVyZmVyaW5nIHdpdGggdGhpcyBwYWdlLg=="),da=l.atob("RGlzYWJsZSBhbnkgYWQgb3Igc2NyaXB0IGJsb2NraW5nIHNvZnR3YXJlLCB0aGVuIHJlbG9hZCB0aGlzIHBhZ2Uu"),ea=function(a,b,c){this.b=a;this.f=new B(this.b);this.a=null;this.c=[];this.g=!1;this.i=b;this.h=c},F=function(a){if(a.b.body&&!a.g){var b=function(){D(a);l.setTimeout(function(){return E(a,3)},50)};C(a.f,a.i,2,!0,function(){l[a.h]||b()},b);a.g=!0}},D=function(a){for(var b=G(1,5),c=0;c<b;c++){var d=H(a);a.b.body.appendChild(d);a.c.push(d)}b=H(a);b.style.bottom="0";b.style.left="0";b.style.position="fixed";b.style.width=G(100,110).toString()+"%";b.style.zIndex=G(2147483544,2147483644).toString();b.style["background-color"]=I(249,259,242,252,219,229);b.style["box-shadow"]="0 0 12px #888";b.style.color=I(0,10,0,10,0,10);b.style.display="flex";b.style["justify-content"]="center";b.style["font-family"]="Roboto, Arial";c=H(a);c.style.width=G(80,85).toString()+"%";c.style.maxWidth=G(750,775).toString()+"px";c.style.margin="24px";c.style.display="flex";c.style["align-items"]="flex-start";c.style["justify-content"]="center";d=A(a.f.a,"IMG");d.className=z();d.src=ba;d.style.height="24px";d.style.width="24px";d.style["padding-right"]="16px";var e=H(a),f=H(a);f.style["font-weight"]="bold";f.textContent=ca;var k=H(a);k.textContent=da;J(a,e,f);J(a,e,k);J(a,c,d);J(a,c,e);J(a,b,c);a.a=b;a.b.body.appendChild(a.a);b=G(1,5);for(c=0;c<b;c++)d=H(a),a.b.body.appendChild(d),a.c.push(d)},J=function(a,b,c){for(var d=G(1,5),e=0;e<d;e++){var f=H(a);b.appendChild(f)}b.appendChild(c);c=G(1,5);for(d=0;d<c;d++)e=H(a),b.appendChild(e)},G=function(a,b){return Math.floor(a+Math.random()*(b-a))},I=function(a,b,c,d,e,f){return"rgb("+G(Math.max(a,0),Math.min(b,255)).toString()+","+G(Math.max(c,0),Math.min(d,255)).toString()+","+G(Math.max(e,0),Math.min(f,255)).toString()+")"},H=function(a){a=A(a.f.a,"DIV");a.className=z();return a},E=function(a,b){0>=b||null!=a.a&&0!=a.a.offsetHeight&&0!=a.a.offsetWidth||(fa(a),D(a),l.setTimeout(function(){return E(a,b-1)},50))},fa=function(a){var b=a.c;var c="undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.iterator&&b[Symbol.iterator];b=c?c.call(b):{next:g(b)};for(c=b.next();!c.done;c=b.next())(c=c.value)&&c.parentNode&&c.parentNode.removeChild(c);a.c=[];(b=a.a)&&b.parentNode&&b.parentNode.removeChild(b);a.a=null};var ia=function(a,b,c,d,e){var f=ha(c),k=function(n){n.appendChild(f);l.setTimeout(function(){f?(0!==f.offsetHeight&&0!==f.offsetWidth?b():a(),f.parentNode&&f.parentNode.removeChild(f)):a()},d)},h=function(n){document.body?k(document.body):0<n?l.setTimeout(function(){h(n-1)},e):b()};h(3)},ha=function(a){var b=document.createElement("div");b.className=a;b.style.width="1px";b.style.height="1px";b.style.position="absolute";b.style.left="-10000px";b.style.top="-10000px";b.style.zIndex="-10000";return b};var K={},L=null;var M=function(){},N="function"==typeof Uint8Array,O=function(a,b){a.b=null;b||(b=[]);a.j=void 0;a.f=-1;a.a=b;a:{if(b=a.a.length){--b;var c=a.a[b];if(!(null===c||"object"!=typeof c||Array.isArray(c)||N&&c instanceof Uint8Array)){a.g=b-a.f;a.c=c;break a}}a.g=Number.MAX_VALUE}a.i={}},P=[],Q=function(a,b){if(b<a.g){b+=a.f;var c=a.a[b];return c===P?a.a[b]=[]:c}if(a.c)return c=a.c[b],c===P?a.c[b]=[]:c},R=function(a,b,c){a.b||(a.b={});if(!a.b[c]){var d=Q(a,c);d&&(a.b[c]=new b(d))}return a.b[c]};M.prototype.h=N?function(){var a=Uint8Array.prototype.toJSON;Uint8Array.prototype.toJSON=function(){var b;void 0===b&&(b=0);if(!L){L={};for(var c="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split(""),d=["+/=","+/","-_=","-_.","-_"],e=0;5>e;e++){var f=c.concat(d[e].split(""));K[e]=f;for(var k=0;k<f.length;k++){var h=f[k];void 0===L[h]&&(L[h]=k)}}}b=K[b];c=[];for(d=0;d<this.length;d+=3){var n=this[d],t=(e=d+1<this.length)?this[d+1]:0;h=(f=d+2<this.length)?this[d+2]:0;k=n>>2;n=(n&3)<<4|t>>4;t=(t&15)<<2|h>>6;h&=63;f||(h=64,e||(t=64));c.push(b[k],b[n],b[t]||"",b[h]||"")}return c.join("")};try{return JSON.stringify(this.a&&this.a,S)}finally{Uint8Array.prototype.toJSON=a}}:function(){return JSON.stringify(this.a&&this.a,S)};var S=function(a,b){return"number"!==typeof b||!isNaN(b)&&Infinity!==b&&-Infinity!==b?b:String(b)};M.prototype.toString=function(){return this.a.toString()};var T=function(a){O(this,a)};u(T,M);var U=function(a){O(this,a)};u(U,M);var ja=function(a,b){this.c=new B(a);var c=R(b,T,5);c=new y(w,Q(c,4)||"");this.b=new ea(a,c,Q(b,4));this.a=b},ka=function(a,b,c,d){b=new T(b?JSON.parse(b):null);b=new y(w,Q(b,4)||"");C(a.c,b,3,!1,c,function(){ia(function(){F(a.b);d(!1)},function(){d(!0)},Q(a.a,2),Q(a.a,3),Q(a.a,1))})};var la=function(a,b){V(a,"internal_api_load_with_sb",function(c,d,e){ka(b,c,d,e)});V(a,"internal_api_sb",function(){F(b.b)})},V=function(a,b,c){a=l.btoa(a+b);v(a,c)},W=function(a,b,c){for(var d=[],e=2;e<arguments.length;++e)d[e-2]=arguments[e];e=l.btoa(a+b);e=l[e];if("function"==r(e))e.apply(null,d);else throw Error("API not exported.");};var X=function(a){O(this,a)};u(X,M);var Y=function(a){this.h=window;this.a=a;this.b=Q(this.a,1);this.f=R(this.a,T,2);this.g=R(this.a,U,3);this.c=!1};Y.prototype.start=function(){ma();var a=new ja(this.h.document,this.g);la(this.b,a);na(this)};var ma=function(){var a=function(){if(!l.frames.googlefcPresent)if(document.body){var b=document.createElement("iframe");b.style.display="none";b.style.width="0px";b.style.height="0px";b.style.border="none";b.style.zIndex="-1000";b.style.left="-1000px";b.style.top="-1000px";b.name="googlefcPresent";document.body.appendChild(b)}else l.setTimeout(a,5)};a()},na=function(a){var b=Date.now();W(a.b,"internal_api_load_with_sb",a.f.h(),function(){var c;var d=a.b,e=l[l.btoa(d+"loader_js")];if(e){e=l.atob(e);e=parseInt(e,10);d=l.btoa(d+"loader_js").split(".");var f=l;d[0]in f||"undefined"==typeof f.execScript||f.execScript("var "+d[0]);for(;d.length&&(c=d.shift());)d.length?f[c]&&f[c]!==Object.prototype[c]?f=f[c]:f=f[c]={}:f[c]=null;c=Math.abs(b-e);c=1728E5>c?0:c}else c=-1;0!=c&&(W(a.b,"internal_api_sb"),Z(a,Q(a.a,6)))},function(c){Z(a,c?Q(a.a,4):Q(a.a,5))})},Z=function(a,b){a.c||(a.c=!0,a=new l.XMLHttpRequest,a.open("GET",b,!0),a.send())};(function(a,b){l[a]=function(c){for(var d=[],e=0;e<arguments.length;++e)d[e-0]=arguments[e];l[a]=q;b.apply(null,d)}})("__d3lUW8vwsKlB__",function(a){"function"==typeof window.atob&&(a=window.atob(a),a=new X(a?JSON.parse(a):null),(new Y(a)).start())});}).call(this);window.__d3lUW8vwsKlB__("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");(function(_){var z=_.document,y=_.location,x,w=1,v=-1;function a(){x=z.getElementsByClassName("fc-confirm-choices");if(x.length)x[0].addEventListener("click",function(){y.reload()});if(z.getElementsByClassName("fc-dialog-overlay").length)w=0;try{v=googlefc.getAllowAdsStatus()}catch(e){}if(v==1&&b()){z.cookie="privacy="+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000)+";expires="+new Date(Date.now()+2592000000).toUTCString()+";path=/";y.replace(y.href);return}/*else if(v>-1&&w){w=0;googlefc.showRevocationMessage()}*/else if(w){try{googlefc.showRevocationMessage();w=0}catch(e){}}setTimeout(a,300)}function b(){var _=z.cookie;return JSON.parse(_.substring(_.indexOf("FCCDCF=")+7).split(";",1))[3][1].length>150?1:0}_.addEventListener("load",a)})(window);
  </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

Later I noticed that after clicking the button "Download data in csv file..." at the bottom of the page GET method send response with information from table (image attached), but the problem is that I don't know how to take this table into my computer by Python code.

[image]

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the data in CSV format for example using `pandas`. Just modify the URL:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://stooq.com/q/d/l/?s=4604.n&d1=20200101&d2=20220507&i=d"

df = pd.read_csv(url)
print(df.head().to_markdown())
```

Prints first 5 rows:

|  | Date | Open | High | Low | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-02 | 115.47 | 115.47 | 115.47 | 115.47 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | 115.4 | 115.4 | 115.4 | 115.4 |
| 2 | 2020-01-07 | 115.46 | 115.46 | 115.46 | 115.46 |
| 3 | 2020-01-08 | 115.61 | 115.61 | 115.61 | 115.61 |
| 4 | 2020-01-10 | 116.91 | 116.91 | 116.91 | 116.91 |

Comment: Unfortunately your code give me the same JS code (The Closure Library) with something like this |------|----|----| repeated many times at the end (probably it should be the table). df Dataframe is empty (0 rows)

Comment: @KrzysztofSobota Maybe your IP got blacklisted. Try to change `User-Header` HTTP header or use different IP address/proxy.

Comment: `import requests 
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Custom user agent'})

session.get('https://httpbin.org/headers')` 

and what about `session` after that?

Comment: @KrzysztofSobota You can use `text = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'...'}).text`

Comment: I paste below these comments my full code.

Answer (score 0):

Now my full code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime as dt

# the investment funds list
number_to_symbol = {
    '1': '2711.n',
    '2': '3187.n',
    '3': '1472.n',
    '4': '4604.n',
    '5': '2735.n'
}

def url_get(num):
    ## Make URL address with the investment fund symbol and dates range (01.01.2020 - today)
    symbol = number_to_symbol[str(num)]
    end_time = f"20{dt.date.today().strftime('%y%m%d')}"
    return f'https://stooq.com/q/d/l/?s={symbol}&d1=20200101&d2={end_time}&i=d'

url_name = url_get(4)
print(f'URL to web-scraping: {url_name}')

df = pd.read_csv(url_name)
print(df.head().to_markdown())
```

Comment: OK, now it is working after some corrections in code. Thanks